# clone url of a pull request

Tags: python, github, github3.py

I'm trying to get the clone URL of a pull request. For example in Ruby using the Octokit library, I can fetch it from the head and base like so, where `pr` is a PullRequest object: `pr.head.repo.clone_url` or `pr.base.repo.clone_url`.
How can I achieve the same thing using github3.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`github3.pull_request(owner, repo, number).as_dict()['head']['repo']['clone_url']`

Comment: Can confirm `as_dict()` proves to be helpful for a number of different objects in the library.